# Hi, i am trying to code a button that allows a user to sign in in visual C++, the program is running but the form dialog is not showing

Tags: c++

i am trying to code a button that allows a user to sign in in visual C++, the program is running but the form dialog is not showing.

Comment: also started programming not too long ago :)

Comment: Nice, but it really helps if you post the code (not everything, just enough to reproduce) :)

Comment: okay....its saying my comment is 755 characters too long...should i break the code into bits?

Comment: @lil_so_so   you can put it in pastebin.com then send us the link

Comment: @LorenceHernandez alright

Comment: http://pastebin.com/f0k8fuNk

Comment: **EDIT** your question and add the code, but **NOT** a link

Comment: @LorenceHernandez No. The code should go into the question, not a pastebin link.

Comment: @LorenceHernandez when i run this in the a normal C++ IDE it works fine. But incorporating it into a button in visual C++ is where i get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> "*when i run this in the a normal C++ IDE it works fine. But incorporating it into a button in visual C++ is where i get stuck.*"

*Console Applications* are **Different** than *Windows Forms*. In other words, if you finished programming some functionality for a *Console Application*, that doesn't mean you can expect the code to work on a Form by just copying and pasting the code into a button or so.

The whole structure of your project would differ, also the coding patterns and design. You need to watch or/and read tutorials about *Form Applications* if you are done with *Console Applications*.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are expecting that your C++ code will work with a Windows Forms program.

```
int main()
```

usually indicates a console application.

```
int CALLBACK WinMain(...)
```

is the entry-point to a graphical Windows-based application.

An example of Windows Forms in C# would be:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      Form form = new Form();
      Button b = new Button();
      b.Text = "Click me!";          
      form.Controls.Add(b);
      form.Show();
      Application.Run(form);
   }
}
```

So depending on what you are trying to do, I would recommend learning the WIN API (C++) or Windows Forms (C#).